# Jenkins GDSL : how to recognize build job in declarative syntax?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In a declarative pipeline, I have this job call :

```
build job: 'myJob', parameters: [
  string(name: 'PARAM1', value: 'value1'),
  string(name: 'PARAM2', value: 'value2'),
], wait: true
```

I would like Intellij recognizes this syntax with a GDSL file. Currently, I have in my GDSL file  :

```
method(name: 'build', type: 'Object', namedParams: [
  parameter(name: 'job', type: 'java.lang.String'),
  parameter(name: 'parameters', type: 'java.util.List'),
  parameter(name: 'propagate', type: 'boolean'),
  parameter(name: 'quietPeriod', type: 'java.lang.Integer'),
  parameter(name: 'wait', type: 'java.lang.Boolean')])
```

But defining a `java.util.List` type for parameter is incorrect : IntelliJ do not expect to have `string()` as parameter.

Any idea ?

Comment: When I 'generate' newest GDSL it comes up with: `method(name: 'build', type: 'Object', params: [job: 'java.lang.String'], doc: 'Build a job')
        method(name: 'build', type: 'Object', namedParams: [parameter(name: 'job', type: 'java.lang.String'), parameter(name: 'parameters', type: 'Map'), parameter(name: 'propagate', type: 'boolean'), parameter(name: 'quietPeriod', type: 'java.lang.Integer'), parameter(name: 'wait', type: 'boolean'),], doc: 'Build a job')`. Which is slighty different. But when I want to load some new GDSL, I have to `invalidate Cache & restart` IntelliJ. Does that work?

Comment: No, if you change the List to a Map, then you have : Type of argument 'parameters' can not be 'List'.  and if we use the list, then Intellij recognizes a list of methods so it does not match a "list of objects"

Comment: What happens if you add this as well to the GDSL file? `if (enclosingCall("parameters")) {
method(name: 'string', type: 'Object', namedParams: [parameter(name: 'name', type: 'java.lang.String'), parameter(name: 'defaultValue', type: 'java.lang.String'), parameter(name: 'description', type: 'java.lang.String')])
 }`. And add `booleanParam` & `choice` as well?

Comment: Do not work : 'No candidates found for method call string'